# hide records with controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

How can I hide records from my controller? i need to hide the records if the column 'retiro' is not null.

Controller:

```
   public function retiro (Request $request){
    $data = [
        'category_name' => 'datatable',
        'page_name' => 'miscellaneous',
    'has_scrollspy' => 0,
    'scrollspy_offset' => '',

    ];
    $records = Registro::where('retiro', '<>', 'on')->get();


    return view('retiro',compact('records'))->with($data);
}
```

if 'retiro' == 'on' should hide the record

the problem is that when printing the records it does not show anything.

[image]
help pls

Answer (score 0):

You can pass all the variables as the second parameter on the `view()` using `compact` instead of doing it separately using the function `with`.

```
public function retiro (Request $request){
    $data = [
        'category_name' => 'datatable',
        'page_name' => 'miscellaneous',
        'has_scrollspy' => 0,
        'scrollspy_offset' => '',

    ];

    $records = Registro::whereNotNull('retiro')
               ->where('retiro','=','on')
               ->get();


    return view('retiro',compact('records','data'));
}
```

Comment: If I want to hide the ones that have value  'on' in the column 'retiro', how do I do it?

Comment: Change the operator as you require it.